# How to add a dependency in makefile only if a recipe (or another dependency) fails?

Tags: makefile, dependencies, gnu-make

I want to achieve the following with gmake:

Have A depend on X. If X passes, we are done. Else A must depend on B (which has a recipe and extra dependencies). I also want to be able to run make in parallel, so I can't start with `A: X B`

I need something like:

```
X:
    $(run_recipe1_and_set_pass_or_fail)

B: B1 B2
    $(run_recipe2)

A: X
    if "X.failed" "evaluate_target(B)" ""
```

I also want to avoid running another make within this process - this would slow things down.

Comment: You cannot do this without invoking another make.

Comment: Make creates the dependency graph *before* executing any rule, so what you ask cannot be done, but invoking another make really wouldn't slow things down much.

Comment: So, should evaluate_target(B) really be a make call to some makefile to make B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if I change the **A** recipe to something like

```
A: X
    $(if -e X.failed,make $(MFLAGS) B,)
```

it works, and it is not bad time-wise when the work done by B is significant.

Comment: Note that if `make` is aware that building `X` failed, it won't execute the actions shown.  So, it has to appear as though `X` was built successfully, even if it failed.

Comment: Two small comments:  first use $(MAKE) instead of make, and next, MFFLAGS is deprecated (values are automatically passed down using the MAKEFLAGS variable).